# Left join, how to specify 1 result from the right?

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

This one is fairly specific, so I'm hoping for a quick fix.

I have a single result in my leaderboard table for each team. In my teams table, I have several results for each team (one result per game to enable team development history).

I want to show each team in the leaderboard once, and have teamID replaced by strName. Problem is, my left join is giving me one record for each team result; I just want a single record.

```
    SELECT * , a.strName AS teamName
FROM bb_leaderboards l
LEFT JOIN bb_teams a ON ( l.teamID = a.ID )
WHERE l.season =8
AND l.division =1
ORDER BY l.division DESC , points DESC , wins DESC , l.TDdiff DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

What do I need to do to this to get a 1:1 output?

Comment: if its a 1:1 relationship, your data must reflect that. You can't get an SQL statement to fix your bad data. if there a many a.IDs for one l.teamID, there's no valid way of doing this

Comment: So I can't 'limit' on the join part to 1 result? I tried 'group by' on the main select by strTeam, but the data wasn't right  :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a SELECT DISTINCT instead, but you'll have to narrow down your select a bit.  So:

```
SELECT DISTINCT l.*, a.strName AS teamName 
...
```

That should filter out the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I'm too new to rep you, sorry.